# How do you set the background image in a BlackBerry application using Java?

Tags: blackberry

how i set background image in java blackberry simulator ?

```
backgroundBitmap = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("background.png");
MainScreen mainScreen = new MainScreen();

HorizontalFieldManager horizontalFieldManager = 
    new HorizontalFieldManager(
        HorizontalFieldManager.USE_ALL_WIDTH | 
        HorizontalFieldManager.USE_ALL_HEIGHT){

        //Override the paint method to draw the background image.
        public void paint(Graphics graphics) {
            //Draw the background image and then call paint.
            graphics.drawBitmap(0, 0, 240, 240, backgroundBitmap, 0, 0);
            super.paint(graphics);
        }            

    };
```

Comment: if u search the forum u can find various posts with same information

Comment: null pointer exception indicates that the code is unable to fetch the png file.where have u placed the file "background.png" ?

Comment: i copy the png image in the res folder of the project

Comment: Please also check the spelling of the file name,may be its the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this blog post:
[How to set Background Image in Blackberry](http://blackberry-tips-bikas.blogspot.com/2009/07/how-to-set-image-in-blackberry.html)

Or this support forum thread:
[drawing bitmap in Mainscreen background](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/drawing-bitmap-in-Mainscreen-background/m-p/211199)

Comment: is there any specific issue or exception that u faced

Comment: Please post some code else nobody will be able to debug your problem

Comment: also make sure that your are inputing the correct name of image file in your code. Null pointer exception in your case is most likely because of wrong name of file. or file not present .. if you just added the file and using eclipse check if the image is available in tree view .. in res folder if not and you have copied there .. press F5 and the try running it again.

Comment: have u tried to debug to check where exactly null pointer exception occurs?

Answer (score 0):

```
     Bitmap bitmapOrig = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("ICON.png");            
      // Create a Bitmap of arbitrary size
      int scaledX = 360;
      int scaledY = 415;
      Bitmap bitmapScaled = new Bitmap(scaledX, scaledY);
      bitmapOrig.scaleInto(bitmapScaled , Bitmap.FILTER_LANCZOS);                       
      bitmapOrig.scaleInto(bitmapScaled , Bitmap.FILTER_BILINEAR, Bitmap.SCALE_TO_FILL);                       
      BitmapField bitmapFieldScaled2 = new BitmapField(bitmapScaled , Field.FOCUSABLE);
     homeScreen.add(bitmapFieldScaled2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
HorizontalFieldManager horizontalFieldManager = new HorizontalFieldManager(
                                HorizontalFieldManager.USE_ALL_WIDTH | 
                                HorizontalFieldManager.USE_ALL_HEIGHT){

    //Override the paint method to draw the background image.
    public void paint(Graphics graphics) {
        //Draw the background image and then call paint.
        graphics.drawBitmap(0, 0, 240, 240, backgroundBitmap, 0, 0);
        super.paint(graphics);
    }    
   protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight){ 
            super.sublayout(240,240);
            setExtent(240,240);
        }        

};
```