# how to add the bitmap as the background to the blackberry screen

Tags: user-interface, blackberry, java-me, blackberry-jde

i want to add the white background screen to my blackberry screen (i.e.,main screen)
after addind that i am able to draw something on to the screen. how to create the background 
and how to draw on that screen. please suggest me. please send me the sample code...
i have written this code but it is not working...

```
Background bg = 
BackgroundFactory.createBitmapBackground(
    Bitmap.getBitmapResource("/Background.png"));
setBackground(bg);
VerticalFieldManager verticalFieldManager = new VerticalFieldManager();


 add(verticalFieldManager);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780230/how-do-you-set-the-background-image-in-a-blackberry-application-using-java see this and this one http://blackberry-tips-bikas.blogspot.in/2009/07/how-to-set-image-in-blackberry.html

Comment: Try replacing `setBackground(bg);` with `getMainManager().setBackground(bg);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
final Bitmap backgroundBitmap = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("blackbg.png");

VerticalFieldManager mainManager = new VerticalFieldManager(Manager.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL | Manager.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR )
{ 
public void paint(Graphics graphics)
{
graphics.clear();
graphics.drawBitmap(0, 0, deviceWidth, deviceHeight, backgroundBitmap, 0, 0); 
super.paint(graphics);
} 
};
```